# Confusion in perl package

Tags: perl, package

I have two files, the below file is "Packages_module.pl",

```
use pack_modules; 
$var = 1;
print "var is $var\n";
&pack_module::check_scope($var);
print "var is $var\n";
```

The second file is "pack_modules.pm", code is below

```
package pack_module;
use Exporter;
@ISA = qw/Exporter/;
@EXPORT = qw/$var/;
our ($var);
sub check_scope 
{
    $var = 3;
}
1;
```

When I run pack_modules.pm I got the following result.

```
    var is 1
    ==========
    Using Module Subroutine:
    var is 1
    ==========
```

First time, it was obvious that '$var' would be 1, but the second time it was again giving 1 rather than 3.  Could any one tell me why the value of "pack_module" is not visible in "Packages_module".

Comment: You didn't export `$var`, but `$var2`. You could also have looked at `$pack_module::var` to test your assumptions. The argument to `check_scope` is ignored. (Oh, and please don't write lowercase modules, or call subs with `&`.)

Comment: @amon by mistake I gave $var2 instead, $var.  Anyway I have edited it, but still it is giving the same output.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem:

You are not exporting `$var`, but `$var2`. If you exported `$var`, the value would change.

Moreover, you use `pack_moudles`, but the package is named `pack_module`.

There are some more minor problems, though: You are calling `check_scope` with a parameter, but you never retrieve the parameter in the body of the subroutine. Instead, you change the value of the global variable `$var`.

Comment: by mistake I gave $var2 instead, $var.  Anyway I have edited it, but still it is giving the same output.

Comment: `pack_module` is not the same as `pack_modules`.

Answer (score 1):

`use pack_modules` is equivalent to `BEGIN { require pack_modules; pack_modules->import; }`

Since your module file is named `pack_modules.pm`, the `require` step works just fine.

It then calls `pack_modules->import` which does absolutely nothing because that file contains a package named `pack_module`.  It doesn't matter what `pack_module` (with no final "s") exports if your main program is importing symbols from `pack_modules` (with an "s").

Change the first line in the module file to `package pack_modules;`, change the sub call in the main program to `pack_modules::check_scope($var);`, and it should work.  (As a side note, don't prefix calls to user-defined functions with `&`.  That's a holdover from Perl 4 which is not necessary in Perl 5 and has side-effects that you probably don't intend to invoke.)

Incidentally, if you had started your program with `use strict;`, it would have given you some additional clues as to the cause of this problem, by complaining that `Global symbol "$var" requires explicit package name` in your main program.